# Will python give you an answer for an infinite solutions linear system?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

The following is the given linear system and my code to solve it.

```
a = np.array([[1,0,8,-5],[0,1,4,-9],[0,0,1,1]])
b = np.array([[6],[3],[2]])
np.linalg.solve(a,b)    #An error is raised saying that Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

I am pretty sure that my code is correct. Thus, does it mean that python will raise error for a linear system who has infinite solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `numpy.linalg.solve`, yes.

But there is another option. [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) finds the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation.

```
In [7]: np.linalg.lstsq(a,b)
Out[7]:
(array([[-2.46764706],
        [ 2.53235294],
        [ 1.42058824],
        [ 0.57941176]]),
 array([], dtype=float64),
 3,
 array([ 13.08121719,   4.33312055,   0.32530484]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs.  linalg.solve (not python) raises error if a is singular or non-square.